# $2^\sqrt{10}$ vs $3^2$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, irrational-numbers, binomial-theorem, number-comparison

Is there a neat way to show that $2^\sqrt{10} < 3^2$?

I have tried raising to larger powers, like $(2^\sqrt{10})^{100}$ vs $3^{200}$ but the problem is the two functions $2^{x\sqrt{10}}$ and $3^{2x}$ are almost equivalent, and there is no point (that I can find) where one function is "obviously" larger than the other.

Looking at $2^{2\sqrt{10}}$ vs $3^4$  I tried to find a way of showing that $2^{2\sqrt{10}} < 2^6+2^4 = 2^4(2^2+1)$ but couldn't see any neat solution.

Any help or hints are appreciated.

edit: I should have specified when I say "neat solution" I was looking for a method readily done by hand. I realise this might be an unrealistic limitation, but it was why I'm interested.

Final thoughts before going to bed: I was looking at the functions $f(x)=2^{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $g(x)=x^2$. At $x=0$, clearly $f>g$. They are equal at $x=2\sqrt{2}$. At $x=4$, again $f>g$. This mean that somewhere in the interval $2<x<4$, $g>f$ (as they are both convex). The task then is to try to find a point such that $x>3$ and $g>f$. But then another fun inequality pops out... $2^{\sqrt{11}}$ vs $10$...

Comment: Is it acceptable if inequality is reduced to, for example, $\sqrt{2}\lt \log_2 3$?

Comment: I added a note to say a solution that might be done by hand. If there is a way to find the value of $log_2 3$ or estimate it neatly then it would be nice.

Comment: @Joseph: Note that $2^1=2$ and $2^2=4$. Since the function $2^x$ is strictly convex, the solution to $2^{\alpha}=3$ must satisfy $1.5<\alpha<2$. Of course, this is not much use here.

Comment: Using music, $3/2$ is a perfect fifth which is approximately 7 semitones or $2^{7/12}$, where taking logs gives $\log_2 3 \approx \log_2(2^{7/12} \cdot 2) = \frac{19}{12}$. Something similar can be done with $9/8$, which is a major second or 2 semitones approximately, $2^{7/6}$. Of course, this doesn't tell us which direction the inequality signs point, but this motivates the examples given below.

Comment: In the same spirit is [Prove that $2\sqrt7 > 5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562588/how-can-i-prove-that-2-sqrt-7-is-bigger-than-5?noredirect=1) and other related questions on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%242%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B10%7D%7D%3C9%24&p=1).

Comment: One more idea in case somebody will see easy way for it: $\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{2}}\lt \log_2 x$ holds for $x\geqslant 3$.

Comment: @zkutch If $x = 126,$ then $\sqrt{1+\frac{x}2} = 8 > 7 = \log_2{128} > \log_2x.$

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley. Correct. I should be more clear:  $\log$ have some "hump" over the root and $3$ is inside. I.e. they have $2$ intersection points. Your example is more right, then second intersection point: first is left from $3$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$2^{\sqrt{10}}=8^{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{9}}}<8^{1+\frac{1}{18}}=2^{\frac{19}{6}}<9.$$
Because $$2^{19}=2(500+12)^2=524288<531441=(700+29)^2=3^{12}.$$
There is another way to show a last inequality, but it's not so nice:
$$2^{19}<3^{12}$$ it's
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{8}\right)^6>2,$$ which is true because
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{8}\right)^6>1+\frac{6}{8}+\frac{15}{64}+\frac{20}{512}>2.$$

Comment: Well, if we are using a calculator to find out these large numbers, why not find out the exact value of $2^{\sqrt{10}}$

Comment: @bigbang I got it by hand. There is another way by the binomial of Newton, but it's ugly.

Comment: took me a minute to process that. That is quite neat indeed. How did you see this so fast? I particularly like $\sqrt{1+\tfrac{1}{9}}<1+\tfrac{1}{18} $. But is there a small typo with $531441=(700+27)^2$ ?

Comment: @bigbang I consider it doable by hand. The calculation isn't that tedious.

Comment: @Joseph This is the Bernoulli inequality. $(1+x)^\alpha < 1+\alpha x$ for certain $\alpha$ and $x$.

Comment: @Joseph  I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I will mark this as an answer later if no further solutions are offered. Finding $2^{19} < 3^{12}$ is quite tedious (at least for me!) although once it is known, the rest is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the maclaurian series of the function $\sqrt{k^2+h}$ for $|h|\leq k$ that ,
$$\sqrt{k^2+h}<k+\frac{h}{2k}$$
Put $k=3$ and $h=1$ we get ,
$$\sqrt{10}<3+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}=3+\frac{1}{6}$$
Hence we must have
$$2^{\sqrt{10}}<2^3\cdot \sqrt[6]{2}=8\cdot \sqrt[6]{2}$$
Therefore we only need to show that
$$8\cdot \sqrt[6]{2}<3^2$$
Or in other words we need to show that
$$\sqrt[6]{2}<\frac{9}{8}=1+\frac{1}{8}$$
or in other words if we raise both sides to $6th$ power ,we need to show that
$$2<\left( \frac{9}{8}\right)^6=\left(1+\frac{1}{8}\right)^6$$
Expanding right hand side using binomial theorem we're left to prove that
$$2<\sum \limits_{k=0}^6 {}^6C_k \cdot \frac{1}{8^k}$$
As the first term in the expansion on right hand side is obviously 1 therefore subtracting 1 both sides leaves us to prove that
$$1<\sum \limits_{k=1}^6 {}^6C_k \cdot \frac{1}{8^k}$$
Now it's working time we don't need to know the full expansion. We'll just leave where the rhs exceeds 1.
Now ,$${}^6C_1\cdot \frac{1}{8}=\frac{6}{8}=\frac{3}{4}$$
$${}^6C_2\cdot \frac{1}{8^2}=\frac{30}{128}=\frac{15}{64}$$
$${}^6C_3 \cdot \frac{1}{8^3}=\frac{20}{512}=\frac{5}{128}$$
let's check now whether this exceeds 1 or not. Adding we get
$$\frac{3}{4}+\frac{15}{64}+\frac{5}{128}=\frac{63}{64}+\frac{5}{128}=\frac{131}{128}=\frac{128+3}{128}=1+\frac{3}{128}>1$$
(Yay!! ;) ) Therefore the inequality is proven. Hence we have
$$2^{\sqrt{10}}<3^2$$

Comment: There is something really interesting about the fact that $\left(\tfrac{9}{8}\right)^6 >2$. Nice. This was what I had been attempting and did not think of turning $9/8$ into a binomial.

Comment: @Joseph at first I again thought to apply the Taylor series for sixth root however it didn't yield the result because $\sqrt[6]{2}\approx 1.122\ldots$ where as $\frac{9}{8}=1.125$ it's quite close. Henceforth I used binomial expansion in order to do so with correspondence to the fact that small changes make large difference ;)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{gather*}
2\times 19^2 = 2 \times 361 = 722 > 720 = 5 \times 12^2,
\ \therefore\ \frac{19}{12} > \sqrt{\frac52}; \\
2^{10} = 1024 < 1025 = 25 \times 41; \\
3^6 = 729 > 725 = 25 \times 29; \\
2 \times 29^2 = 2 \times 841 = 1682 > 1681 = 41^2; \\
\therefore\ 2 \times 3^{12} > 25^2 \times (2 \times 29^2) > 25^2 \times 41^2 > 2^{20}, \ \therefore 3^{12} > 2^{19}; \\
\therefore\ \log_23 > \frac{19}{12} > \sqrt{\frac52},
\ \therefore \log_23^2 > \sqrt{10}, \ \therefore 3^2 > 2^{\sqrt{10}}.
\end{gather*}

---

"Another fun inequality" was recently added to the question.

Just for fun, then (because the new inequality cannot be considered as part of the question, this cannot be considered as part of an answer, but it's too long for a comment):
\begin{gather*}
5^5 = 3125 > 3072 = 12 \times 256 = 12 \times 2^8,
\ \therefore\ 5^{13} > 12 \times 10^8; \\
29^3 = (30 - 1)^3 = 30^3 - 3 \times 30^2 + 3 \times 30 - 1 =
27000 - 2700 + 90 - 1 \\
= 24389 < 24400 = 61 \times 400,
\ \therefore\ 29^6 < 61^2 \times 2^4 \times 10^4; \\
61^2 = 3721 < 3750 = 6 \times 5^4,
\ \therefore\ 29^6 < 6 \times 10^8,
\ \therefore\ 5^{13} > 2 \times 29^6; \\
2^{10} = 1024 < 1025 = 25 \times 41,
\ \therefore\ 2^{60} < 5^{12} \times 41^6; \\
41^2 = 1681 < 1682 = 2 \times 841 = 2 \times 29^2,
\ \therefore\ 2^{60} < 5^{12} \times 2^3 \times 29^6; \\
\therefore\ 2^{60} < 5^{12} \times 2^2 \times 5^{13},
\ \therefore 2^{58} < 5^{25},
\ \therefore\ \log_25 > \frac{58}{25}; \\
83^2 = 6889 > 6875 = 11 \times 625 = 11 \times 25^2,
\ \therefore\ \sqrt{11} < \frac{83}{25}; \\
\therefore\ \sqrt{11} < 1 + \log_25 = \log_2{10},
\ \therefore\ 2^{\sqrt{11}} < 10.
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 1):

A trick is to blow up the gap

$[2^\sqrt{10},\;3^2] → [2^{\sqrt{10}-3},\;9/8] → [2,\;(9/8)^{\sqrt{10}+3}]$

$1.26^3 = 2.000376$

$(9/8)^2 = 81/64 = 1+1/4+1/16 > 1.26$
$(9/8)^{\sqrt{10}+3} > (9/8)^6 > 1.26^3 > 2\qquad\qquad$ ⇒ RHS is bigger

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM, $\frac{3 + 10/3}{2} > \sqrt{10} \implies \frac{19}{6} > \sqrt{10}$. Thus:

$$2^{19/6} \ ? \ 9 \iff 8 \cdot 2^{1/6} \ ? \ 9 \iff 2 \ ?  \ (1 + 1/8)^6$$

$$\iff 2 \ ? \ 1 + 6/8 + 15/64 + 20/512 + \text{other positive terms}$$

$$\iff 2 < 1 + 96/128 + 30/128 + 5/128$$

hence $2^{\sqrt{10}} < 2^{19/6} < 9$.

Comment: Michael Rozenberg already mentioned this in his answer.

Comment: The other answer also mentions the same thing and I have not used the Bernoulli inequality. Besides, this answer fills in the details.

Comment: Yes, but it also shows *how* to get there, and there is borderline merit in that. Your answer would benefit from an elaboration into how the partial sum is obtained (but then again Amrit got there first...)

Comment: I put the music theory part as a comment above because determining which way the inequality points is harder than I thought. When I'm done, I'll put the music theory part in.